# How to validate a user-supplied charset string for mb_*() functions?

Tags: php, validation, encoding, character-encoding

A variable (`$my_charset` below) holds a user-supplied charset / encoding string, expected like `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, or `Windows-1251`. How can I programmatically validate it? I have user-supplied text (`$my_text` below) at disposal too, supposedly in this encoding.

My solution so far:

```
$is_valid = @mb_check_encoding($my_text, $my_charset);
```

I don't like it, because:

- It uses the error control operator `@` to suppress errors (like *Warning:  mb_check_encoding(): Invalid encoding "some-invalid-encoding"*) which is bad programming practice.
- The `false` returned value doesn't help me to distinguish a bad charset string from a valid charset string and incorrectly encoded text.

PHP provides `mb_list_encodings()` and `mb_encoding_aliases()` functions that I could use to build a list all supported encodings, and check in a case-insensitive manner if the user-supplied encoding is included in this list. I don't like this solution either, overkill. Needs to call `mb_encoding_aliases()` for each item returned by `mb_list_encodings()` (over 50).

Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the supplied charset on its own with:

```
$is_valid = @mb_check_encoding('', $my_charset);
```

The error control operator may be icky, but there's nothing wrong with using it here. It exists for a reason beyond evil. And you don't have any worry about conflating an unsupported encoding with incorrectly encoded text.

---

If you still want to avoid that, using `mb_list_encodings` and `mb_encoding_aliases` isn't overkill - ~50 encodings with ~4 aliases each is *not* a lot. Though if you don't want to run those on each request you can use them to generate a static array and load that instead.

#### Example:

```
$encodings = mb_list_encodings();
foreach ($encodings as $enc) {
    $encodings = array_merge($encodings, mb_encoding_aliases($enc));
}
$encodings = array_change_key_case(array_fill_keys($encodings, true));
var_export($encodings);
```

This'll dump out valid PHP that you can paste directly into a php file. You could instead serialize it with [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) or [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and unserialize it later, whatever you're into.

It uses the encodings as keys instead of values so your lookup will happen in O(1) time rather than O(n). The [`array_change_key_case`](http://php.net/array_change_key_case) is there to lowercase them all for easy lookup with:

```
$is_valid = isset($encodings[strtolower($my_charset)]);
```

Comment: You improved both my initial ideas, nice. I will accept the answer. If somebody gives yet a better solution, I will change. 

The empty string is valid with any valid charset string, thus `mb_check_encoding()` will return `false` only when the charset string is invalid. Didn't think about that trick.

Generating a static array once instead of on each request is more efficient, yes. It's so easy to forget about some rarely used PHP functions, like `array_change_key_case()` or `array_fill_keys()`. Makes your implementation quite elegant.